# Mi bot de discord.py no funciona

Tags: python, discord.py

soy nuevo en esta plataforma, y en python tambien, tengo un bot que estaba haciendo en una pagina, tal la usaba como si fuese el programa donde escribia el codigo, solo que no se guardaba en mi pc, ahora estoy intentando pasarlo a mi pc, con el programa pycharm, pero no se que pasa, pero al ejecutar el bot, al instante se deja de ejecutar, y pone el mensaje `Process finished with exit code 0`, segun estuve viendo, eso es que el codigo no tiene error, pero aun no logro poder dejar el codigo abierto, para que pueda cargar el bot y usarlo cuando este abierto en mi pc, alguien sabe como "solucionar" esto?

PD: este es mi codigo, no creo que tenga algo que ver con eso, pero lo pongo por las dudas:
PD2: Lo acabo de intentar correr en visual studio code, no sale el process finished with exit code 0, pero aun asi se sigue cerrando, no se que pueda ser, pero agrego esta informacion por que puede llegar a ser util

```
import os
import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import urllib.request
import json
import time
import asyncio
import urllib
import datetime
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

bot = Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
async def on_ready(self):
  print(f'Conectado a {self.user}')

@bot.event
async def on_ready(*, self):
    print('Ready')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"actualmente en  {self.bot.guild.member_count:,} servers!")
                              )

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

###########################MODERACION#############################################

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@bot.command(category="Moderacion", name='kick')
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="lo hice por que quise"):
      if member.id in [ctx.author.id, bot.user.id]:
        return await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Error",
          description=f"No te puedes kickear a ti mismo o al bot!",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     )
      await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Kick",
          description=f'El usuario {member.name} ha sido devuelto al overworld "{reason}" dijo el acusado',           
          color=discord.Color.purple())
     )
      await member.kick(reason=reason)

@bot.command(name='ban')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="no tenia razon"):
       if member.id in [ctx.author.id, bot.user.id]:
        return await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Error",
          description=f"No te puedes banear a ti mismo o al bot!",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     )
       await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Ban",
          description=f"El usuario {member.name} ha sido empujado al vacio, segun el que cometio el acto {reason}",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     )
       await member.ban(reason=reason)


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=0):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Clear",
          description=f"He borrado {amount} mensajes!",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     , delete_after=3)


@bot.command(aliases=["Unban"])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name,
                                               member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"UnBan",
          description=f'el usuario {user.name} ha sido desbaneado',
           color=discord.Color.purple()))
            return


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="no tenia escusa"):
       if member.id in [ctx.author.id, bot.user.id]:
        return await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Error",
          description=f"No te puedes mutear a ti mismo o al bot!",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     )
       guild = ctx.guild
       mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

       if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole,
                                          speak=False,
                                          send_messages=False,
                                          read_message_history=True)

       embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Muted",
          description=f"Se le ha cerrado la boca al usuario {member.name}, segun el {reason}",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
    
       await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
       await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@bot.command(aliases=['Unmute'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")

    await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
    await ctx.send(f"el usuario {member.mention} ya puede hablar")

@bot.command(aliases=["Role"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def role(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    if member.id in [ctx.author.id, bot.user.id]:
     return await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
     title=f"Error",
     description=f"No puedes darte roles a ti mismo o al bot!",
     color=discord.Color.purple())
    )
    guild = ctx.guild
    rol = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=f"{role}")
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
      title="role",
      description=f"el usuario {member.mention} ha recibido el rol **{role}**",
      color=ctx.author.color
    ))
    await member.add_roles(rol)


@bot.command(aliases=["Remove_Role", "Remove_role", "remove_Role"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def remove_role(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    if member.id in [ctx.author.id, bot.user.id]:
     return await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
     title=f"Error",
     description=f"No puedes quitar roles a ti mismo o al bot!",
     color=discord.Color.purple())
    )
    guild = ctx.guild
    rol = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=f"{role}")

    await member.remove_roles(rol)
def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))

###############################comandos personales#############################

@bot.command(alias="Ender")
async def ender(ctx):
 await ctx.send('violeta de los cojones https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/875897346272153621/875900438736691280/desconocido.jpeg')

@bot.command(aliases=["Oscar", "óscar", "Óscar"])
async def oscar(ctx):
 await ctx.send('es un cabron')

@bot.command(aliases=["dark"])
async def Dark(ctx):
 await ctx.send('emote-man')

@bot.command(aliases=["bet"])
async def Bet(ctx):
 await ctx.send('señor co-owner')

@bot.command(aliases=["Zawer"])
async def zawer(ctx):
 await ctx.send('como que no sabes quien es zawer?? hombre! zawer es mi idolo, te dejo su canal de twitch: http://www.twitch.tv/zawerlives?sr=a y su servidor de discord: https://discord.gg/zrbEaf6')

@bot.command(aliases=["deican"])
async def Deican(ctx):
 await ctx.send('perrete :dog:')

@bot.command(aliases=["teletubbie", "tubbie", "Tubbie"])
async def Teletubbie(ctx):
 await ctx.send('F coso rojo :sob:')

@bot.command(aliases=["Cl", "cl", "cL"])
async def CL(ctx):
 await ctx.send('adios...   Putos')
########################################################################

moderacion = "moderacion"

@bot.command()
async def ayuda(ctx, category):

    if category == moderacion:
      
      embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Moderacion",
        description=
        "Muestra el uso de los comandos de moderacion sus funciones",
        color=discord.Color.purple())
    embed.add_field(
        name="Mute/unmute",
        value=
        f"mutea/desmutea al usuario especificado, su uso es *mute/unmute [mencion] (necesitas el permiso de gestion de mensajes para usar el comando)"
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Ban",
        value=
        f"banea al usuario especificado, su uso es *ban [mencion] (necesitas el permiso de banear miembros para usar el comando)"
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Unban",
        value=
        f"desbanea al usuario especificado, su uso es *unban [nombre del usuario, incluyendo su numero] (necesitas el permiso de banear miembros para usar el comando)"
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Kick",
        value=
        f"saca al usuario del servidor, su uso correcto es *kick [mencion de usuario] (necesitas el permiso de banear miembros para usar el comando)"
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Clear",
        value=
        f"Borra cierta cantidad de mensajes, su uso es *clear [cantidad] (necesitas el permiso de gestion de mensajes para usar el comando)"
    )
 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


#################################OTHERS############################################


@bot.command(aliases=["Vote"])
async def vote(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Aqui tienes el enlace para votar!",
        description=f'[aqui!](https://top.gg/bot/868923021967122472/vote)',
        color=discord.Color.purple()
    )

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@bot.command(aliases=["Confesion", "confesión", "Confesión"])
async def confesion(ctx, *, mensaje):
    embed = discord.Embed(
      title="confesion:",
      description=f'{mensaje}'. format(mensaje),
      color=discord.Color.purple())
      
    channel = bot.get_channel(886427215468843048)
    
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
   

@bot.command(aliases=["Say"])
async def say(ctx, *, mensaje):
  embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{mensaje}". format(mensaje), description = f"", color = ctx.author.color)
  embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author.name}")

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command(aliases=["Avatar"])
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  embed = discord.Embed(title = f"el avatar de {member.name} es:",
  color = discord.Color.purple)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.Member.avatar_url)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

###############################GIVEAWAYS###########################################
import random

@bot.command(aliases=["Gstart", "GStart"])
@commands.has_role("mods discord")
async def gstart(ctx, mins : int, *, prize: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Giveaway", description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.author.color)
   
    embed.set_footer(text = f"termina en {mins} minutos desde ahora!")
    if mins == 1:
      embed.set_footer(text = f"termina en {mins} minuto!")

    my_msg = await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    await my_msg.add_reaction(f"")

    await asyncio.sleep(mins)

    new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))

    winner = random.choice(users)
    
    ganador = discord.Embed(title = f"{winner.mention} ha ganado el premio!", description = f'su premio es: {prize}')

    await print(f"{winner.mention}", ganador)

@bot.command(aliases=["Poll"])
async def poll(ctx, opcion1, opcion2, *, opcion3, opcion4, opcion5, opcion6, opcion7, opcion8, opcion9, opcion10):
  await ctx.send(f"{opcion1}, {opcion2}")

###################################ERRORS#########################################

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
 if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
   await ctx.channel.send(
     embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Error",
          description="No tienes suficientes permisos!",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     )
 if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
   await ctx.channel.send(
     embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Error",
          description="Ese comando esta mal escrito o no existe",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     )
 if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
   await ctx.channel.send(
     embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"Error",
          description="Medio que falta algo ahi no? quizas una palabra? o una mencion?",
           color=discord.Color.purple())
     )

################################BOTSTATS#########################################
from platform import python_version
from discord import __version__ as discord_version
from datetime import timedelta
  
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print('termine de cargar')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot.run("ODY4OTIzMDIxOTY3MTIyNDcy.YP2toA.YqvhrvQ3zcYZxA6wEqENcLhKuXQ")
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

```
 title=f"UnBan",
          description=f'el usuario {user.name} ha sido desbaneado',
           color=discord.Color.purple()))
            return
```

Disculpa tampoco se mucho, pero este return no deberia estar retornando algo en especifico, o que esta haciendo dicho return?, talvez sea eso.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver, el `return` siempre está de forma explicita o implícita por lo que no ponerlo tiene el mismo efecto que ponerlo y si se especificada algo simplemente ese es el valor que retorna la función al ser llamada, por defecto es `None` y si estuviera usando ese valor tendría un error de tipo `None type ...` pero claramente se dice en la pregunta que **No tiene errores**. Por favor lee [answer]